# Setting up tomcat within a SERVERPILOT configured environment

Tags: tomcat, nginx

I have a serverpilot configured cloud server. I created a new app inside that and set up a tomcat listening to 8080. I am able to access that tomcat if I use domain name:8080. Now I want to modify the nginx reverse proxy to make it work at port 80.

File I tried modifying:

/etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/wfm.d/main.conf

Existing code

```
location /{
    proxy_pass $backend_protocol://$backend_host:$backend_port;
}
```

New one I added:

```
location /{
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/wfm:8080;
}
```

I restarted my nginx after that but it doesn't work and the browser page keeps loading and finally timesout.

Comment: `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/wfm;`?

Comment: @DusanBajic that solved it... silly me...

Answer (score 1):

The way to send requests to non-PHP apps with ServerPilot is not to make any customizations to Nginx but instead to [use a .htaccess file to proxy requests to the port your app is listening on.](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-run-apps-in-any-language.html)

Your .htaccess file will look like this:

```
RewriteRule index.html http://localhost:8080/ [P]
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:8080/$1 [P]
```